# how do you cut a row in excel depending on if it contains a particular string using a vb script?

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am writing a VBScript that should open an HTML file, copy it into excel and then hopefully cut certain rows out depending on criteria. NOTE: Also sorting rows based on contents is an acceptable alternative.

For example if I had rows

```
1 aasfsfas
2 qrwqrwqrqp
3 czxzxczx
4 qwrrqwpqwr
```

and I wanted the ones that contained "p", I would either want this to appear:

```
2 qrwqrwqrqp
4 qwrrqwpqwr
```

or it to be sorted so the "p" rows were at the top.

This is the code to open the Excel file:

```
Set Excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Excel.Application.Visible = True
Excel.WorkBooks.Open csv
' App Activate, bring to front
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").AppActivate Excel.Name
```

I'm a bit stuck as to where to go from here.

MAIN GOAL FROM THIS QUESTION: to sort rows in excel using a vb script

Comment: Do you need code to handle HTML importing or just the row filtering?

Comment: You should split your problem into smaller simpler ones. Then ask question for a specific problem. Can you Read HTML/Parse HTML/Create Excel file/Write data in the excel file/Parse string/Order string/Save excel file/...

Comment: @NathanTuggy edited question (row filtering is the goal of this quesiton)

Comment: Use regular expressions to check for the text you want and then delete the rows that do not match.  You can do this either before or after it is imported into Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should probably cut the mustard (partially tested):

```
' Make sure there's a header row if not already
Excel.Rows("$1:$1").Insert -4121 'xlDown
Excel.Range("$A$1").Formula = "#"
Excel.Range("$B$1").Formula = "Text"
' Do the actual filtering; "=*p*" should be replaced with whatever actual criteria you need;
'     assumes column 2 is the relevant one
Excel.Range("$A$1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter 2, "=*p*"
```